# $stateChangeSuccess not firing on href-transitioning

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Am I correct in my conclusion that $stateChangeSuccess won't fire unless I use $state.transitionTo? For instance:

```
//in app config
.state('detail.zoom', {
        url: '/zoom/{itemId}',
        templateUrl: 'detail/zoom-partial.html'
    })

//in html
<a href="#/zoom/{{item.id}}" >ZOOM IT!</a>

//in directive
scope.$state.transitionTo('detail.zoom', { itemId: item.id});

//in some controller
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {alert('done transitioning!')});
```

the event from transitionTo triggers $stateChangeSuccess, but thats not the case for the href version. Is there a way to get events fired for both types of transition equally?

Comment: May be you are looking for $routeChangeSuccess

Comment: @Codezilla, I can test this, but i doubt it, since this is in reference to angular-ui/ui-router, a seperate library for angularjs, not the default routeProvider. See here [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: oh, I know now what my mistake was. I had a nested state but didn't use the full url path in the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks to me like you are using a nested state. shouldn't the be a separate url for the state called "detail". 
meaning the full url is  url: 
    '/detail/{itemId}/zoom',

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was missing! Thank you so much :) 
A bit confusing when the state is declared using only the partial url, but in the html you of course have to use the full path

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    alert('done transitioning!')
});
```

Comment: While this may be a correct answer, it would be a great improvement if you added an explanation of why your code works/what it does.

Answer (score 1):

from version 1.0.0 of ui-router , you need to inject

> $transition

service

and use this methods inside controllers:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function() {});
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your directive can you try scope.$apply()

```
//in directive
scope.$state.transitionTo('detail.zoom', { itemId: item.id});
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: the scope.$state.transitionTo is no problem, so no $apply() needed. it is the href that doesn't trigger the event. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten nested URLs with using a caret ^ before:

```
.state('detail.zoom', {
    url: '^/zoom/{itemId}',
    templateUrl: 'detail/zoom-partial.html'
})

<a href="#/zoom/{{item.id}}" >ZOOM IT!</a>
```